# How to disable 3D Touch Link Preview

Tags: swift, wkwebview, 3dtouch

Since iOS10 the "**3D Touch link preview**" has been enabled by default, but how can I disable it in my app? Documentation says it's possible by [setting allowsLinkPreview to false](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415000-allowslinkpreview), but doing it separately for each use case is too much code. There must be an easier way, right?

I thought this would do it, but I get error **"Property does not override any property from its superclass"**. I hope there's just a small mistake, help would be appreciated:

```swift
extension WKWebView {
    override open var allowsLinkPreview: Bool {
        set {
            // no-op
        }
        get {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you define it as `var allowsLinkPreview: Bool` by removing `override open` ?

Comment: @YunusErenGüzel no, doesn't disable link preview that way

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `WKWebView` with a convenience initializer and set the property inside of it. Then use this initializer to instantiate web views.

```
extension WKWebView {
    convenience init(allowsLinkPreview: Bool) {
        self.init()
        self.allowsLinkPreview = allowsLinkPreview
    }
}
```

Another option is to make a subclass of `WKWebView` and add this convenience initializer there.

Comment: Good idea, but not generic solution: I would still need to call a custom init with parameter